# Does the addition operation performed by late binding in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I have some function which performs addition operation on to variant data types

```
Public Function Sum(value1, value2)
    Sum = value1 + value2
End Function
```

Does this addition operation performed by late binding or not?

Or late binding performed only when I invoke some method on variant data type but not with binary operations?

I'm also wondering is late binding used when I add Object data types in VB .NET (Option Strict is turned off), dynamic data types in C#.

Thank you.

Comment: Erm, late/early binding has no bearing on mathmatical operators. Can you rephrase the question to make sense?

Comment: + is mathematical operation if we are dealing with numeric types, not strings or variants (I think so...)

Comment: So where does late/early binding come into it?

Comment: Is late binding used to perform + operation on two variant variables? If not then what is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to early /late binding. I think you are referring to the data types for `value1` and `value2`? The question is confusing however as it is tagged VB6 but you use `Return` which is not a valid keyword in VB6

In the case of VB6 both `value1` and `value2` will be variants so they could be numeric or strings (or even objects). The function will also return a Variant

- If you call the function with two strings - the sum result will be the concatenated string: `value1value2`
- If you pass in two numeric values then the sum will be the arithmetic sum of the values: `value1` + `value2`

Is is always best to avoid this type of programming and define the types that you require to prevent unexpected result

**EDIT:**

From MS VB.NET documentation but this is very similar for VB6:

The + Operator (Visual Basic) has the primary purpose of adding two numbers. However, it can also concatenate numeric operands with string operands. **The + operator has a complex set of rules that determine whether to add, concatenate, signal a compiler error, or throw a run-time InvalidCastException exception.**

This is nothing to do with early or late binding because that is to do with the compiler knowing which methods, properties and events an object has at compile time (early binding) and not knowing these at compile time (late binding)

The latter can result in runtime errors because you may have mistyped a method name and the compiler can't pick that up until it tries to execute the line and cannot find the method you typed. Have a look at the following for more information: [Early vs Late Binding](http://www.thecodenet.com/articles.php?id=11)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that VB6 does not have return, however question is related to VB6 :)

Comment: @Artyom My answer is correct for VB6 - am I on the correct lines of that you are asking?

Comment: I'm not using this type of programming, I just wanted to know what is happening here. As I understand, everything is made at runtime. Types of two values are checked and then it decides how to make an addition operation with those data types. So I want to know, is this process is a late binding. If it is not, then what is it?

Comment: @Artyom This process is called *implicit type coercion* or *implicit type conversion*. Late-binding is different. You can read more about implicit type conversion [here (pdf)](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/pt199511.pdf)

Comment: Here is the VB6 documentation on the `+` operator. It explains the rules about the input types and the result type of the operation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242731(v=VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The only case when a late-bound call is made in your function is when one of the Variant arguments is an object reference. When evaluating the + operator (or any other expression) on a reference argument, first its DISPID_VALUE (0) member is called late-bound (through `IDispatch::Invoke`) and the retval is used in the expression. If the retval is an IDispatch reference it's DISPID_VALUE is called recursively. That's why you can use `recordset("ID")` instead of `recordset.Fields.Item("ID").Value` in expressions (kind of).

If explicit object references of known types (interfaces) are used in an expression (e.g. + operator), the compiler emits code that calls default property early-bound which results in much simpler evaluation at run-time.